# Error in load a model saved by callbakcs.ModelCheckpoint() in Keras

Tags: keras, hdf5, tensorflow-lite

I saved my model automatically by `callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()` with a HDF5 file.

```
# Checkpoint In the /output folder
filepath = "./model/mnist-cnn-best.hd5"

# Keep only a single checkpoint, the best over test accuracy.
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', 
                                             verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                             mode='max')

# Train
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

When I load a model, an error occured.

```
  model = keras.models.load_model("./mnist-cnn-best.hd5")

  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py", line 251, in load_model
    training_config['weighted_metrics'])
KeyError: 'weighted_metrics'
```

If I load model with param '*compile=False*', it works correctly.

I know the normal way to save model in keras is:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

By the way, this error also happened when me convert this model by Tensorflow Lite.
But I don't know what's wrong with my model.
Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: The function `load_model()` can load model saved by func `save_model()`. In class `callbacks`, model saved by `model.save()`. What's the difference between these ways? How can I load a model saved by the second way?

Comment: Are you using the same Keras versions to save and load the model?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm using same version:2.2.2 both in  _Windows 10_ and _Ubuntu 16.04_ platform, this problem occured in _Windows 10_, works fine in _Ubuntu 16.04_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit a similar problem that yields the same error message, but the cause might be different than yours:

**Code:** (Tensorflow 1.11 and tf.keras.**version**: 2.1.6-tf)

```
 if load_model_path.endswith('.h5'):
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(load_model_path)
```

**Error message:**

```
  File "...../lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 251, in load_model
    training_config['weighted_metrics'])
KeyError: 'weighted_metrics'
```

And I found out it's because the model was saved in an older Keras version.
I had to comment out the code related to `weighted_metrics` to be able to load the model. However, it's just a workaround before I can find a sustainable solution to the mismatching problem. Interestingly, `@fchollet` just added `weighted_metrics` to the latest Keras version recently (Oct 2018).
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/saving.py#L136
I hope this will help the people who hit the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't figured out the answer to this yet, I think I've got it.

I haven't dug into the code to exactly figure out why, but basically the model checkpoint callback can only be loaded with the `load_weights()` function, which is then used for evaluation.

If you want to save a model that you can load to train again later you need to use `model.save` and `model.load_model`. Hopefully helpful to someone who wanders upon this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually use this is as follows:

```
def create_model():
    <my model>
    <model.compile>
    return model
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=<val>, monitor=<val>, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

classifier = create_model()
classifier.fit(<your parameters>)
classifier.evaluate(<your parameters>)

loaded_model = create_model()
loaded_model.load_weights(filepath)
y_pred = loaded.model.<predict_method>(test_set,verbose=<val>)
'''
```